# Speeding up and fixing phone numbers from CSVs with Regex

Tags: python, strings, regex, python-2.x, csv

I've hodgepodged together an attempt to extract all phone numbers from all CSVs in a directory, regardless of where they are and what format they're in.  I want all phone numbers to be printed to a compilation CSV with no repeat elements in the format `8885551234` with NO leading ones.  E.g., `1 (510) 533-2134` would become `5105332134`, as would `510-5332134` (and the latter would count as a dupe and fail to be written).

My challenges are that the numbers are in different formats, in different columns (and sometimes in several columns), and that the files in the directory are, in total, many gigabytes in size.

What I came up with, first, fails to weed out numbers that start with 0 or 1 (though it does seem to "skip" the 1 in 11-digit numbers); second, I need checked by a regexpert to see if it is even doing what I want (identifying and printing phone numbers); and third, is far too slow:

```
import csv
import re
import glob
import string

with open('phonelist.csv', 'wb') as out:
    seen = set()
    output = []
    out_writer = csv.writer(out)
    csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
    #csv_files2 = glob.glob('*.csv')
    for filename in csv_files:
        with open(filename, 'rbU') as ifile:
            read = csv.reader(ifile)
            for row in read:
                for column in row:
                    s1 = column.strip()
                    result = re.match(
                        r'.*(\+?[2-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?-?\(?[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)? ?[0-9][0-9][0-9]-?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*', s1) or re.match(
                        r'.*(\+?[2-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?-?\(?[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)?-?[0-9][0-9][0-9]-?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*', s1)
                    if result:
                        tempStr = result.group(1)
                        for ch in ['(', ')', '-', ' ']:
                            tempStr = tempStr.replace(ch, '')
                        if tempStr not in seen:
                            seen.add(tempStr)
                            output.append(tempStr)
    for val in output:
        out_writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: You say that you intend to strip out the country code, but I don't see that happening in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [compiled regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile).

Since you are looking for the pattern anywhere within a string, use [`re.search()` instead of `re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).  Actually, the behaviour is not exactly the same.  `.search()` will return the leftmost match, whereas `.match()` using your original pattern will return the rightmost match, since the initial `.*` is greedy.  The backtracking that is necessary to accomplish a rightmost match would be a source of inefficiency.

By using `.search()`, which performs a search not anchored to the start of the subject string, you can also eliminate the capturing parentheses and use `.group(0)` instead.

You can also shorten the regex by using `\d` (match any digit) and `{n}` (match the previous element *n* times).  Since your two regular expressions differ by only one character, combine them, using a `[ -]` character class to cover both cases.

In the canonicalization step, you want to eliminate all non-digits, so just do that instead.

```
regex = re.compile(r'\+?[2-9]?\d?\d?-?\(?\d{3}\)?[ -]?\d{3}-?\d{4})')
…

match = regex.search(s1)
if match:
    canonical_phone = re.sub(r'\D', '', match.group(0))
    if canonical_phone not in seen:
        seen.add(canonical_phone)
        output.append(canonical_phone)
```

Comment: This takes about 20% the time of my original script!  That's exciting.  However, it includes numbers that start with 1, so that the two numbers mentioned above come out as `5105332134` and `15105332134`, and therefore as dupes (I want the latter to output the same way as the former, and it looks from the compiled regex like it should only start with 2-9, right?)

Comment: As noted in my comment on the question, I don't see that you tried to strip out the country code anywhere in your original program. I just reproduced the bug, that's all. It should be trivial to fix, though, using a capturing pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Simple comments here :

- You don't need both `seen` and `output`: the set will be enough to store the unique numbers and print them later on.
- You should keep your reading logic and your writing logic independent by performing the former and then the latter. That would make things clearer and remove an unneeded level of nesting.
- Probably because I still have my morning eyes but I can't see the difference between the two regexps.